# Can't run require('opencv4nodejs')

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv

I'm using macOS Monterey 12.2.1, Apple M1. And in the project directory, I installed opencv-build and opencv4nodejs by this script code:

`"scripts": { "postinstall": "npm i opencv-build && npm i opencv4nodejs" }`

When I run `cv = require('opencv4nodejs')`, I got this error message and I can't understand it. How can I run this code correctly?

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/david/Desktop/project2/main.js
/Users/david/Desktop/project2/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/cv.js:47
    throw err
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/david/Desktop/project2/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/build/Release/opencv4nodejs'
Require stack:
- /Users/david/Desktop/project2/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/cv.js
- /Users/david/Desktop/project2/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/opencv4nodejs.js
- /Users/david/Desktop/project2/main.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/david/Desktop/project2/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/cv.js:40:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/david/Desktop/project2/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/cv.js',
    '/Users/david/Desktop/project2/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/opencv4nodejs.js',
    '/Users/david/Desktop/project2/main.js'
  ]
}

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Node 14.18.1, then uninstall opencv4nodejs.

Run `export CXXFLAGS="-std=c++14 -Wno-c++11-narrowing"`

Run `npm install opencv4nodejs`